# sub query methods with linq not returning all objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I think i am officially going slightly crazy :) i have had something working with Linq to XML but becuase of speed issues i have had to rework and transform the data an place it in a DB instead.  Now i am reworking my plumbing code to take into account Linq2Sql but the method sub querying the returned method results that was working with the XML provider just doesnt seem to want to work now?

---

**UPDATE**

I have found that my console app that i am using to display the results is doing some funny things.  For instance if i call the methods in this order:

```
        var available = manager.DoesHotelHaveAvailabilityForPeriod("BTHA", start, end, 10);
        var results = manager.GetRoomTypesForPeriod("BTHA", start, end);
```

The availability works but the getRoomTypes doesnt return roomTypes, if i swap them around then the opposite happens, the room types are returned but the availabilility then returns false, so that is why i was getting odd results, i just do not know why this would happen?

---

For instance my repository returns this:

```
   public LinqAvailabilityRepository()
    {
        var context = new AvailabilityDataContext();
        _typesTable = context.GetTable<RoomType>();
    }
```

my top level method call does this

```
    public List<RoomType> GetRoomTypes(string hotelCode)
    {
        var results = from rt in _repository.RoomTypes
                      where rt.Rooms.Any(r => r.HotelCode == hotelCode)
                      select rt;

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

this works when i output it to the screen in a console

```
    public List<RoomType> GetRoomAvailability(string hotelCode, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int daysRequired)
    {
        var items = GetRoomTypes(hotelCode);

        var results = items.Select(rt =>
            new RoomType
            {
                id = rt.id,
                Code = rt.Code,
                Description = rt.Description,
                Name = rt.Name,
                Rooms = rt.Rooms.Select(r =>
                    new Room
                    {
                        id = r.id,
                        RoomRates = r.RoomRates.Where(rr => rr.EffectiveDate >= startDate &&
                            rr.EffectiveDate <= endDate).ToEntitySet()
                    })
                    .Where(r => r.RoomRates.Count == daysRequired)
                    .OrderByDescending(r => r.RoomRates.Count()).ToEntitySet()
            });

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

But when i call the following, the rooms collection is 0, but i know that the method returns rooms based on the same query as i outputted it before when i directly call the method above.

```
    public bool DoesHotelHaveAvailabilityForPeriod(string hotelCode, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int daysRequired)
    {
        var items = GetRoomAvailability(hotelCode, startDate, endDate, daysRequired).ToList();

        return ((from i in items
                where i.Rooms.Count == daysRequired
                select i).Count() > 0);
    }
```

this also happens for a couple of other methods where other objects are not returned when i try and sub query like this, I am trying not to repeat myself with the same code, is there something i should know or am not doing?

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late night programming does not help anyone :)  i was being a fool and creating objects based on the object model created by the linq to SQL data context (Room, RoomType, RoomRate Etc), i was searching around and saw a snippet of code saying you cant create objects directly from a query based on your data objects (after i recieved an error) so refactored and created and mapped the model to several corresponding DTO objects and that seems to have cleared up the problem:

Example code change:

```
public List<RoomTypeDTO> GetRoomAvailability(string hotelCode, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int daysRequired)
{
        var items = GetRoomTypesForPeriod(hotelCode, startDate, endDate);

        var results = items.Select(rt =>
            new RoomTypeDTO
            {
                id = rt.id,
                Code = rt.Code,
                Description = rt.Description,
                Name = rt.Name,
                Rooms = rt.Rooms.Select(r =>
                    new RoomDTO
                    {
                        id = r.id,
                        RoomRates = r.RoomRates.Where(rr => rr.EffectiveDate >= startDate &&
                            rr.EffectiveDate <= endDate).ToList()
                    })
                    .Where(r => r.RoomRates.Count == daysRequired)
                    .OrderByDescending(r => r.RoomRates.Count()).ToList()
            });

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to look.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

So your function `GetRoomAvailability()` returns correct in some cases and in some cases not?

What about tracing it down and use some breakpoints to see where it all is different?

I am not sure but why are you converting your return value from `GetRoomAvailability()` ToList() and then doing it when recieving it again in `DoesHotelHaveAvailabilityForPeriod()`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're hitting issues because you are not explicitly nor implicitly loading the navigation collections before you call `.ToList()` on your first query.

Try this (or something like it):

```
public List<RoomType> GetRoomTypes(string hotelCode)
{
    var results = from rt in _repository.RoomTypes.Include("Rooms.RoomRates")
                  where rt.Rooms.Any(r => r.HotelCode == hotelCode)
                  select rt;

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Also remember that calling `.ToList()` on the query doesn't call `.ToList()` on the navigation items.

It would probably be even better if you created a private method that returned the `IQueryable<RootType>` rather than the list.

```
private IQueryable<RoomType> QueryRoomTypes(string hotelCode)
{
    var results = from rt in _repository.RoomTypes.Include("Rooms.RoomRates")
                  where rt.Rooms.Any(r => r.HotelCode == hotelCode)
                  select rt;

    return results;
}

public List<RoomType> GetRoomTypes(string hotelCode)
{
    return this.QueryRoomTypes(hotelCode).ToList();
}

public List<RoomType> GetRoomAvailability(string hotelCode, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int daysRequired)
{
    var items = this.QueryRoomTypes(hotelCode);

    var results = items.Select(rt =>
    // ...
}
```

The general rule is to only call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` when returning to the external caller. Don't use them in intermediate queries.

Comment: This is interesting, the code above calls to list to many times as i was desperatly trying anything :) i have updated the question with does new findings, would this solution help in that scenario?

Comment: I think include is a EF operation, not a general Linq to SQL one as i cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Yes, Include is EF specific. The LINQ to SQL Equivalent is setting the Context's LoadOptions using the LoadWith<T>(t => t.child).

Comment: Sorry folks. My mistake. Try using the `LoadWith` method. Another option is to not expose the linq-to-sql objects publicly, but instead create your own objects and build them inside the query. You're kind of doing that already where you create the new `RoomType` instance. You get far better control with your own objects and it helps to create a disconnected data model.

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes there is problem with DateTime comparison.

For e.g. If you try to find an entry on date, lets say 30-08-2011 and if the database has entry Date 30-08-2011 12:50:30 , then it will not return the result.

What you can try is.. just make time of the dates in sql to 00:00:00 and check if you get correct results.

Comment: Hi Marshal, thanks for the response, the DateTime comparison is  working fine.